# not able to identify correct 'div' using bs4 python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the data but I am unable to identify the correct 'div' as there are two of them with same class. If i try to do a find on the parent of second 'div' and then call its children, it simply gives none.

The data to be scraped is the admission status, school name, GRE, GMAT scores.

I am doing this with the help of Python and beautifulsoup

Here is my code below

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.clearadmit.com/livewire/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


container = soup.find('div', attrs = {'class' : 'livewire-container'})
print(container)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The posts are loaded via Ajax from external source. You can use following example how to load them:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.clearadmit.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

params = {
    "action": "livewire_load_posts",
    "school": "",
    "round": "",
    "status": "",
    "orderby": "",
    "paged": "",
}

for page in range(1, 5):  # <--- increase number of pages here
    print("Getting page {}..".format(page))

    params["paged"] = page
    data = requests.post(url, data=params).json()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["markup"], "html.parser")

    for entry in soup.select(".livewire-entry"):
        status = entry.select_one(".status")
        name = status.find_next("strong")
        details = entry.select_one(".lw-details")

        print(
            "{:<25} {:<30} {}".format(
                status.get_text(strip=True),
                name.get_text(strip=True),
                details.get_text(strip=True),
            )
        )
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Getting page 1..
News                      All Schools                    
Accepted from Waitlist    Michigan / Ross                Round: Round 2
Accepted from Waitlist    UT Austin / McCombs            GMAT: 640 Round: Round 2
Accepted                  Johns Hopkins / Carey          Round: Round 3
Accepted                  Michigan / Ross                GPA: 3.65 GRE: 322 Round: Round 3
Accepted from Waitlist    Michigan / Ross                GPA: 3.1 Round: Round 2 | Michigan
Note                      All Schools                    GMAT: 740 Round: Round 1 | Africa
Accepted                  INSEAD                         GPA: 3.5 GMAT: 770 Round: Round 4 | Taiwan
Accepted                  INSEAD                         GMAT: 750 Round: Round 4 | India
Interview Invite          Berkeley / Haas                GPA: 3.72 GMAT: 740 Round: Round 1 | IL
Enrolled                  Duke / Fuqua                   GPA: 3.59 GRE: 333 Round: Round 2 | Miami
Interview Invite          Georgetown / McDonough         GRE: 307 Round: Round 3 | Arlington
Accepted                  USC / Marshall                 GPA: 3.4 GMAT: 720 Round: Round 2 | NY
Note                      NYU Stern                      Round: Round 1
Enrolled                  Berkeley / Haas                GMAT: 760 Round: Round 2 | Canada
Waitlisted                Duke / Fuqua                   GRE: 314 Round: Round 2
Note                      All Schools                    Round: Rolling Admissions
Interview Invite          Columbia                       GPA: 3.5 Round: Round 3 | NY
Accepted                  UNC Kenan-Flagler              GMAT: 740 Round: Round 1
Interview Invite          MIT Sloan                      GPA: 3.6 GMAT: 740 Round: Round 3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Getting page 2..
Rejected                  Columbia                       GPA: 3.6 GRE: 331 Round: Round 3 | IL
Interview Invite          Northwestern / Kellogg         GPA: 3.6 GRE: 331 Round: Round 3 | IL
Waitlisted                Duke / Fuqua                   GMAT: 760 Round: Round 2 | Canada

...
```

---

EDIT: Added pagination.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is very helpful. Any idea to fetch the link for other pages of the website?

Comment: @AdityaGupta Updated my answer.